# Performance of HTML <datalist> w/ Many Rows & List Inputs?

Tags: html, ajax, autocomplete, html-datalist

I have a table with ~500 rows that consists of 3 columns: `Name | autocomplete <input> | button`.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td><input/></td> <!-- todo - add autocomplete -->
    <td><button> click me </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charles</td>
    <td><input/></td> <!-- todo - add autocomplete -->
    <td><button> click me </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Will</td>
    <td><input/></td> <!-- todo - add autocomplete -->
    <td><button> click me </button></td>    
  </tr> 
  <!-- more rows (not shown) ... --> 
</table>
```

I'm working to have the `<input>` be an autocomplete [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

However, the inputs to my `datalist` consist of ~1000 entries. As a result, I'm debating between:

1. pre-populate each `input` with the ~1000 entries in each `input`'s `datalist`
2. fire AJAX request when the user types into the `input`, whose 'onComplete' will populate the `input`'s `datalist` with the results
3. ??? (another option I haven't thought of)

Is it even reasonable to implement option 1, i.e. create ~500 (each row) `<input>`'s with a 1000 (size of list) `datalist` options? Or will that bring the page's loading screeching to a halt?

Comment: Why not try it out first?

Comment: Excellent point, Evan! I'm working now to find out its performance since option #1 might be simpler, i.e. from a development point of view. However, I figured I'd ask about it since someone might have already encountered this situation and I'd like to know their experience.

Comment: @Kevin what approach did you decide to use finally?

Comment: Hi @kbsbng - I went ahead with # 2. Unfortunately I haven't really used it, so I don't know if was a good choice or not.